# vb.net 2008 / Imports System.Transactions?

Tags: vb.net, transactions

Using vb.net 2008.
I am trying to use TransactionScope but when I put "Imports System.Transactions" at the top of my module it is not taking it. Do I need to do some setting or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add a reference to System.Transactions, right click on the project in solution explorer and select Add Reference.

[image]